# How to support localization with redux-form normalize

Tags: javascript, localization, redux-form

In one of our forms, we need to show a decimal number at an input field. The requirement is that we support both locales for decimal numbers: `12.5` and `12,5`. 
We need to keep the value as a number so i am trying to use the `normalize` method.

```js
 function normalize(value: string) {
   return +value
     .replace(/^[0]+/, "") // numbers can't start with a zero
     .replace(/[^\d.,]/, "") // decimals allowed digits and . ,
     .replace(/[,]/,"."); // actual numbers are saved with .
}
```

The problem is that it works for `.` but not for `,` since redux-form doesn't allow to show difference values for the view and the store.

One option would be to store the value as string and to change it using the `format` method, but when i need to send this data to the server i need it to be numbers and not string.

Is there a better solution that we can still save the value as number but support `,` and `.` ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend giving [The Redux Form Value Lifecycle](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/docs/ValueLifecycle.md/) a good read.

To answer your question:

1. Store data as a number in the redux store
2. Use `format` to turn a number from the redux store into a localized string for the input
3. Use `parse` to change the user input into a number for the redux store
4. Only use `normalize` if you need to enforce some formatting or constraints on the values *entering* the redux store

For the full "magical autoformatting experience" you can see in [this example](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/examples/normalizing/), you'll need to store the number as a string in the redux store and parse it to a number during form submission.